# Evernote Integration With PHP

Tags: php, evernote

I have successfully done with the authentication of Evernote with PHP.

And I have got this response.

```
Array ( [oauth_token] => S=s1:U=6316e:E=144fcfdfdb9:C=13da54cd1ba:P=185:A=maheshchari-2599:V=2:H=6da806fe92b9289cf0334f04e2afdc55 [oauth_token_secret] => [edam_shard] => s1 [edam_userId] => 405870 [edam_expires] => 1395813907897 [edam_noteStoreUrl] => https://sandbox.evernote.com/shard/s1/notestore [edam_webApiUrlPrefix] => https://sandbox.evernote.com/shard/s1/ )
```

Now, I want the list of notebooks of  the user which has been authenticated with evernote.

I have done a lot of research online but I couldnt find any thing which helps, I have came to know that guid is necessary to get the list of notebooks.

From where I can find that? And how can i access the notestore and userstore?

How can i call the functions of notestore and userstore to fetch the data of user's account and user's notes in php?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Evernote SDK for PHP](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-php), you can list notebooks like the way below:

```
$client = new Client(array('token' => $authToken));
$noteStore = $client->getNoteStore();
$notebooks = $noteStore->listNotebooks();
```

All the API references can be found [here](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/).

Also, you shouldn't make your token public.  Please make sure your token string you put can't be used any more.  If you need more help on this, you can get [supports from Evernote developer support](http://dev.evernote.com/support/faq.php#getsupport).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-php
go to this link and download this zip then go to sample folder then go to client folder and run EDAMTest.php page.
and add authtoken.